# std::unique_ptr attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been on Unity for quite a while and came back to do some C++ using Visual Studio 2015. I came across this class definition

```
class A
{
public:
  A();
  virtual ~A();
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A& operator=(const A&) = delete;

private:
  …
}
```

This class is dynamically allocated like the following:

```
ObjPtr obj = ObjPtr(new A());
```

where `ObjPtr` is a type defined and looks like:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<A> objPtr;
```

and adding these created objects using to a `std::vector<ObjPtr>` using `std::move`. At one point, I need to loop through the list of objects, and if I find something that satisfies my criteria, keep a copy of it.

```
ObjPtr keep;

for(auto& object : GetObjectList() )
{
  if(/*check if its the object I want*/)
  {
    keep = object;
  }
}
```

Where GetObjectList returns a `const std::vector<ObjPtr>&`.

But I'm getting an “attempting to reference a deleted function”. I did some googling and tried to remove the `= delete` part and even commented the 2 lines out. I even tried to do

```
ObjPtr keep = std::move(object);
```

But I'm still getting the deleted function error. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or point me to some resources that can help?

Comment: What is the type of `ObjectList`?

Comment: @vsoftco Updated my post!

Comment: Are you sure `ObjectList` isn't `const`?

Comment: @dwnenr [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec934755a76df4bf). Make sure also you use `keep = std::move(object);`.

Comment: @vsoftco `keep = std::move(object);` would leave a dead pointer in the vector.

Comment: @JamesRoot Updated the post. Yeah it is a const

Comment: @dwnenr Well there you are. You can't move out of a constant unique pointer. Also, as many others are saying, this isn't how `unique_ptr` was intended to be used.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why would it be a problem? The `unique_ptr` move constructor does its job. Maybe I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @vsoftco What would that leave in the vector?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz A `unique_ptr` that was moved from. The ownership was transferred outside the vector, isn't it?

Comment: @vsoftco Right, which doesn't seem to be what the OP wants. There's no evidence he wants the vector to lose ownership of the object.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz *an object in a valid but unspecified state*? (17.6.5.15). That's why I said that probably I don't understand what exactly are you trying to say. IMO it's perfectly fine to sink `unique_ptr`'s into containers and move them back, as long as you know what you're doing. Ahh OK I got now the end of your comment. Yes, I agree. For a moment I though I may have learnt something blatantly wrong about unique_ptr's, and that you cannot move them into containers. But now it's clear what you meant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied. Even if the managed object could (but yours can't).

You have a couple of alternatives here (all with different effects):

- Change the type of `keep` to a non-owning raw pointer (aka `A *`) and use `keep = object.get();`.  This is safe if and only if you know you won't use `keep` longer than `ObjectList` (or, more precisely, the object you take the address of) exists.
- Move the `std::unique_ptr` out of the container, that is, use `keep = std::move(object);`. Of course, now you have a gap in `ObjectList`. (I realize you have edited your question to say that `ObjectList` is `const` which means that you cannot modify and hence not move objects out of it.)
- Change the type of `ObjPtr` to `std::shared_ptr<A>` if you want shared ownership semantics.
- If you absolutely want a *copy* of the object, you could add a `virtual` member function to `A` that clones the object polymorphically.

  ```
  class A
  {
  public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() = 0;
    …
  };
  ```

  You then implement that function in every leaf `class` derived from `A`. In your loop, you then use `keep = object->clone();`. For this, you probably want to make the copy constructor `protected` but don't `delete` it.

  Don't use `keep = std::make_unique<A>(*object);` because it would not respect the actual (dynamic) type of the object and always slice to an `A`. (Since your `A` is not copyable, it wouldn't work anyway.)

Answer (score 5):

What makes a unique pointer "unique" is that there can only exist one such pointer to an object. If you made a copy of a unique pointer, you'd have two things that each owned the underlying object. When each one was destroyed, the object would be destroyed, leading to a double delete.

If you need multiple ownership, use a `shared_ptr`. If you don't need ownership in the code that keeps a copy, don't keep a copy but instead keep a pointer or reference.